# Proving $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n$ exists

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If $\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} = 1 + \beta_n,\ n= 1,2,...,$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \beta_n$ converges absolutely, then the limit $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = b \in \Bbb R$ exists

For $1>\varepsilon>0$, there is an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for $n>N$, $|\beta_n| < \varepsilon $.

Then $\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} > 0$ and so each $b_k$ has the same sign for $k>N$. We also have $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} = 1$. Thus $ \frac{1}{1 - \varepsilon} < \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} < \frac{1}{1 + \varepsilon}$. Then if $b_k > 0$, $\frac{b_n}{1 - \varepsilon} < b_{n+1} < \frac{b_n}{1 + \varepsilon}$; if $b_k < 0$, $\frac{b_n}{1 - \varepsilon} > b_{n+1} > \frac{b_n}{1 + \varepsilon}$. I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the logarithm here, because it will turn your fraction into a difference than you can then turn into a serie, I explain :

Let $c_n = ln(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}) = ln(b_n) - ln(b_{n+1})$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i = ln(b_1) - ln(b_{n+1})$ and regarding to the hypothesis, we also have $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i = \sum_{i=1}^n ln(1+\beta_n)$

Since $\beta_n$ is the term of a convergent serie, it goes to zero at infinity. So $ln(1 + \beta_n)$ is equivalent to $\beta_n$ and you should be able to use usual series comparison theorems (just a first-order Taylor, $\sum \beta_n$ being absolutely convergent) to prove that the series $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i$ indeed converge to a limit $l$.

Then it holds that $b_{n+1} = e^{ln(b_1) - \sum_{i=1}^n c_i} \rightarrow e^{ln(b_1) - l} = b_1 e^{-l} $